# Why is the new array null even though I populate it with values from other initialized arrays?

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
//row 0 are questions and row 1 are answers

public String[][] correctAnswers = {
    {"What name was on the door the day he ran away?"},
    {"Mike Smith"}
};

public String[] wrongAnswers = new String[]{"Rory Mcilroy", "Bob Jones", "Arnold Palmer"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("new game","onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

    //Get three random indexes for the wrong answers here   
    //Get the three wrong answers for buttons

    String[] afb = new String[3];
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.nextInt(2);
        System.arraycopy(wrongAnswers, a, afb, i, wrongAnswers.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your array is null? You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Because in debugger all of the values in afb are null.

Comment: Why you aren't using `for(int i = 0; i < afb.length; i++)` is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Look that you have `i<4` in your loop. And you just have `3` positions in your array. **You have to remember that arrays start on position `0`, not `1`**.

If you look at [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) you can see what happens:

> Copies an array from the specified source array

You are copying the `wrongAnswers` array.

> beginning at the specified position

Your `a` variable could be 0 or 1.

> to the specified position of the destination array

If your `i` variable it's `4` then it couldn't get any value from `wrongAnswers` array and it will crash with an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

What can you try it's to put your `System.arraycopy` without the `for` loop. Like this:

```
System.arraycopy(wrongAnswers, 0, afb, wrongAnswer.length - 1, wrongAnswers.length);
```

I really don't understand why do you need a random number to do this (look that with `System.arraycopy` you can copy all the array in one time).

Comment: I changed it to "i < 3" but array afb is still null when I try to copy values over.

Comment: @drtillmann I changed my answer. I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want **to get all the non-repeated indexes in random order**, you may consider to copy the entire array and then **shuffle** it.

```
private static void shuffle(String[] ar){
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
    String s = ar[index];
    ar[index] = ar[i];
    ar[i] = s;
  }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("new game","onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

    //Get three random indexes for the wrong answers here   
    //Get the three wrong answers for buttons

    String[] afb = new String[3];       
    System.arraycopy(wrongAnswers, 0, afb, 0, afb.length);

    //prints the original array
    for(int i=0; i<afb.length; ++i)
        System.out.println(afb[i]);

    shuffle(afb);

    //prints the shuffled array
    for(int i=0; i<afb.length; ++i)
        System.out.println(afb[i]);
}
```

The above `private static void shuffle(String[] ar)` is an edit from the method found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/1575188) provided by the user [PhiLho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15459/philho).